# What is the meaning/purpose of *.pid files in /var/run

Tags: init-script, sysvinit, fhs

I'm quite new in Linux world, and now I'm trying to understand [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) principles.

In `/var/run` I found about ten `*.pid` files like `crond.pid` which contain just PIDs.

There are more than ten processes running in the system and just ten files.

So what is their purpose and what generated them?

Comment: See also: [What is a .pid file and what does it contain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296170/what-is-a-pid-file-and-what-does-it-contain) and [What are pid and lock files for?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/what-are-pid-and-lock-files-for). One should add that this is a simple way of finding a daemon process by name, but not a particularly robust/well-programmed one. Accidental shutdowns may leave orphan pidfiles, upon which a daemon restart fails because "daemon is still running". Auto-cleaning resource (e.g. a server socket on a known port) would seem better nowadays.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The purpose of these files is to provide an easy means for other processes to communicate with them (e.g. send signals). This only makes sense for long running services, that’s why you find much less such files than processes running.

Usually those files are created by the service they represent, you will find a parameter like `--pid-file` or so in the invocation.

Depending on the type of [init-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) you will find files for services in different places.

- sysv-init: `/etc/init.d/`
- upstart: `/etc/init/`
- systemd: `/etc/systemd/`