# Search by file extension using grep command in /var/run

Tags: ubuntu, grep, var

I want to search files by using `grep` command in the directory `/var/run`

`/var/run` stores the processes running in the system and it has files with `pid` extension. I want to get a list of all the files with the extension `pid` .

Command I am using `sudo grep -nr '*.pid' .`  (I am executing this command from the directory `/var/run` )

It shows no output. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: That is not a correct description of `/var/run`.  At best you are labouring under the misapprehension that PID files are a necessity, when in fact [they are a dangerous and deeply flawed mechanism](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotCreatePIDFiles) that the world is at oh-so-long last finally learning the wisdom of getting rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `grep` is wrong tool, use `find` with correct options

If you do `stat /var/run` you'll quickly find out that `/var/run` is symlink to `/run` directory.

```
$ stat /var/run
  File: /var/run -> /run
  Size: 4           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 696874      Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-02-07 13:17:01.225178554 +0800
Modify: 2017-12-18 20:44:12.898113636 +0800
Change: 2017-12-18 20:44:12.898113636 +0800
```

So you really need `/run` directory instead. As for searching files with specific filename, you need `find` command:

```
$ find /run -name "*.pid" 
/run/charon.pid
/run/starter.charon.pid
/run/dhclient-wlp2s0.pid
```

Because some files in that directory belong to root or other system users, you may need to use that command with `sudo`.

*Alternatively*, you can use `-L` flag to allow following symlinks and call `find` on `/var/run`:

```
$ find -L  /var/run -name "*.pid" 
/var/run/charon.pid
/var/run/starter.charon.pid
/var/run/dhclient-wlp2s0.pid
```

Please note also, that `grep` is wrong tool for the job. `grep` is for searching text patterns *inside* text files, not in their filenames.

You also mentioned:

> /var/run stores the processes running in the system and it has files with pid extension

That's actually incorrect. Process information belongs in `/proc`.  The `.pid` files are  simply used by *some* programs to prevent multiple copies of same process running (well, one of possible ways these files can be used). See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8296204/3701431) for reference, as well as [this highly voted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12818/85039) on unix.se.  While the directory belongs to root user, please don't assume that it's for startup and daemon apps only; scripts initiated with root permissions by user could write to the directory just as easily.

Comment: Using `/var/run/` will avoid the need for `-L`.  Also bear in mind that Ubuntu 14 LTS uses Upstart, and the thing that actually prevents multiple copies of the same program running as multiple processes is Upstart knowing not to start them.

Comment: @JdeBP    Sorry, `find /var/run` alone doesn't work in my case. `find --version` reports `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git`.  So at least with my version of GNU `find`  it does need `-L` flag. I am not sure about how BSD `find` handles things.    Nice to know that about 14.04 Ubuntu's Upstart feature, though  that doesn't help with scripts which  want to avoid multiple copies of self running, so at least on askubuntu we have been suggesting to use `.pid` files for that.

Comment: You speed-read what I wrote.  Read it again slowly, and note the exact sequence of characters.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP  Oh...Adding final slash works...